# Anther person is getting my fb messages!

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chat, facebook-account

My phone was stolen over Labor Day. I have two small business's so logged onto my fb on a relatives phone to keep up with messages. She is still getting my fb messages on her phone and they cannot seem to delete my account off of her phone. Help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Facebook and change your password.  Make sure that any 2FA matches an email address or phone you have access to.

Once the password is changed and you have verified that you can pass 2FA if necessary, [logout of Facebook on all your devices](https://www.howtogeek.com/744436/how-to-log-out-of-facebook-on-all-your-devices-at-once/)

Anyone who was logged in will be logged out and they won't have the new password so will stay that way.